# Realtime data binding JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, knockout.js, streaming, real-time

I've got this requirement where i'm not very successful in breaking through client side technology. Hope someone might have already solved this kind of puzzle on what i don't wanna break my head again and burn my time.

My Requirement is :

- I've a server which does have a data processing engine which will feed
  a database for every 30 seconds on an average.
- I need a client side web application where i want to draw some graphs
  as per data generated by my server Engine.
- I could find suitable library for my Graphing requirements (Flotr2)
- I've setup a Node.js server with socket.io comm for my back end data
  streaming.

I can simply listen on socket using plain js and call functions to draw graphs.

But, my application has to be highly configurable. i want multiple column data from Database to draw on single graph to fulfill my requirement (which means, multiple values on single element).

If i implement my client-side using plain JavaScript, at some point my code would become un-maintainable and also i might be re-inventing existing wheel.

So, i'm looking for client side library for data binding (one value to one element, multiple values to single element, multiple values to multiple elements)

I'm basically a back-end and mobile guy but not JS guy. I've browsed web and got some random suggestions to use Knockout.Js, Angular.js, Backbone.js, Meteor.js, which i can't rely one.

**Edit:**

I've already tried Knockout.js for client-side data binding. I'm stuck with my second and third use-case (**Many values to single element and many values to many elements**).

> Let say from server i got {"a":55,"b":5,"c":46} as data. I've two HTML
>   elements with id "x","y". I want to bind values a,b to element "x" and
>   values b,c to element "y". is it possible? any simple fiddle would be
>   great help.

So, can somebody point me right direction and share your thoughts here.

Comment: here I'm talking about approx. 50 variables means 50 key value pairs are to be transferred at an avg.of 30sec Interval. if i use AJAX that would crash my server with polling. To avoid that i'm using Socket.Io which will send me asynchronous data stream that means I'm going to save all Requests. That means half my server Network can be saved. Hope i made you clear about my idea.

Comment: Well if it's a real time system that you want you need to have the infrastructure

Comment: @Typo, I've covered serer-side infrastructure to handle any traffic. But sametime i shouldn't eat-up my visitor network band-width. So, for real-time streaming where you know there will be continuous data coming, polling would be over head on user network. So, we use latest HTML5 capabilities like Socket.IO for data streaming. I'm not very good at browser side javascript, were i need help to choose frameworks to build browser-side application. Please check my updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**knockout.js**- Good for data binding to your view. Less learning curve easy to implement.

**angular.js**- this is a full stack client side framework (MVC/MVVM). Provide controllers, services and modules to architect your front end. Data binding is only one part of angular.js job. You will need to bit more time on learning as it's more complex framework than knockout.

**ember.js** - if the data data update frequency is high and rendering performance is an issue to you this could be an option as well. Rendering performance is much higher in ember than angular.js and knockout.js (according to my experience. Do some testing on your data model, supported browsers before coming to a conclusion).

There are some more good frameworks like backbone.js for your requirements. But I don't have any experience with them.

**Good read** - http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/javascript-data-binding-frameworks

Edit 1:

knockout.js computed function can be used to bind multiple values to an element.

### View model

```
var self = this;
self.valueA = ko.observable(55);
self.valueB = ko.otbservable(5);
self.valueC = ko.otbservable(46);
self.valueX = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.valueA() + self.valueB();
});
self.valueY = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.valueB() - self.valueC();
});
```

### HTML

```
Value X, <span data-bind='text: valueX'> </span>

Value Y, <span data-bind='text: valueY'> </span>
```

Look examples here http://www.knockmeout.net/

Comment: Thanks @Duminda for our comparison of different options. link you provided is a dead-link. Please check and update link.

Comment: please check my updated question for more specific Knockout.Js question. ope you have some pointers on Knockout.js for me.

Comment: not sure what you meant by 'I want to bind values a,b to element "x"'. If you want to do calculation and/or decision on base values and set a value to an element you can use computed() function. (fixed the broken link in the answer)